# Search keywords from one dataframe in another and merge both . Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like following

```
dfx=pd.DataFrame({'Title':
                  ['These cats are very cute',
                   'dogs and horse is a loyal animal',
                   'chicken layes eggs full of proteins',
                   'lion is the king of jungle']})
```

and another data frame of keyword like this

```
kwx=pd.DataFrame({'Tag':['cats','cute','dogs','horse','chicken', 'proteins', 'lion','jungle','eggs'],
                 'Area':['animal',np.NaN,'animal','animal','bird','food','animal','place','food']
                })
```

What is want to do is to search `Tag` from `kwx` in `Title` of `dfx`. And if tag is present, merge the kwx row of that tag with title.

Here is what I have done.
Split the title and search each tag in title, and return the first two match results.

```
dfx['splittitle'] = dfx['Title'].str.lower().str.split()#strop title
dfx['matchedName'] = dfx['splittitle'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in kwx['Tag'].tolist()])
dfx[['term1','term2']] = dfx.matchedName.apply(pd.Series).iloc[:,0:2]#return only two matches
dfx.drop('splittitle',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Output

```
Title                                 matchedName                        term1    term2
These cats are very cute              ['cats', 'cute']                   cats     cute
dogs and horse is a loyal animal      ['dogs', 'horse']                  dogs     horse
chicken layes eggs full of proteins   ['chicken', 'eggs', 'proteins']    chicken  eggs
lion is the king of jungle            ['lion', 'jungle']                 lion     jungle
```

The next step i performed is to merge the `term1` and `term2` column with `kwx` dataframe

```
merged_dfx = dfx.merge(kwx,  how='inner',left_on=['term1'],right_on='Tag',suffixes=('_1','_2'))
merged_dfx = merged_dfx.merge(kwx,  how='inner',left_on=['term2'],right_on='Tag',suffixes=('_1','_2'))
merged_dfx.drop(['Tag_1','Tag_2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Output

```
Title                               matchedName                     term1   term2   Area_1  Area_2
These cats are very cute            ['cats', 'cute']                cats    cute    animal  
dogs and horse is a loyal animal    ['dogs', 'horse']               dogs    horse   animal  animal
chicken layes eggs full of proteins ['chicken', 'eggs', 'proteins'] chicken eggs    bird    food
lion is the king of jungle          ['lion', 'jungle']              lion    jungle  animal  place
```

The output i want. Instead of confining to only first two match, i want all results and want dataframe in following shape
Output

```
Title                                  term                             Area
These cats are very cute               ['cats',cute']                   ['animal']  
dogs and horse is a loyal animal       ['dogs', 'horse']                ['animal','animal']     
chicken layes eggs full of proteins    ['chicken', 'eggs', 'proteins']  ['bird','food','food']
lion is the king of jungle             ['lion', 'jungle']               ['animal',  'place']
```

PS: Because of space constraints here to make code pretty i dropped matchedName columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=kwx.Tag.tolist()#puts all strings in Tag into a list
dfx['term']=dfx.Title.str.split(' ')# Puts Title values into a list in a new colum term
dfx['term']=dfx['term'].map(lambda x: [*{*x} & {*t}])#Leverages sets to find strings both in t and term
dfx=dfx.assign(Tag=dfx.term)#creates a column called Tag
newdf=pd.merge(dfx.explode('Tag'),kwx).drop(columns=['Tag'])#Expands dfx to allow merging to kwx
newdf.groupby(['Title',newdf['term'].str.join(',')])['Area'].agg(list)#Groupby Title and term and add area to list
  


Title                                term                 
These cats are very cute             cute,cats                     [nan, animal]
chicken layes eggs full of proteins  proteins,chicken,eggs    [food, bird, food]
dogs and horse is a loyal animal     horse,dogs                 [animal, animal]
lion is the king of jungle           jungle,lion                 [place, animal]
```